# Flutter cannot run app on iOS device, but iOS simulator and Android working

Tags: ios, flutter

I wrote app and it's working on Android, Android emulator, iOS emulator but not working on iOS device. It works previously, but I do not test it for a lot of days and now I cannot do it. When I run app, I see splash screen and nothing else happen for a lot of minutes. There is no error, but I see in VSC console:

```
Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected...
Still attempting to connect to the VM Service...
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might have more details.
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with --host-vmservice-port to use a specific port known to be available.
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 52448
This was attempt #50. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 52559
This was attempt #100. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 52660
This was attempt #150. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.
```

Comment: Try to run from Xcode

Comment: Yeah, it works!
First Xcode please to manually run `pod install`, after that build was finished successfully and now I can run it from VSC ;)